# Spark - PIC similarities, is a smaller value more similar or less?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

This is in Spark 1.6.2

I'm trying to use Power Iteration Clustering, but having an issue. It takes an `RDD[(Long,Long,Double)]` representing a sparse affinity matrix, but I'm unclear on the similarity values. The [run function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.PowerIterationClustering) has this to say about the `similarities` parameter:

> an RDD of (i, j, s<sub>ij</sub>) tuples representing the affinity matrix, which is the matrix A in the PIC paper. The similarity s<sub>ij</sub> must be nonnegative. This is a symmetric matrix and hence s<sub>ij</sub> = s<sub>ji</sub>. For any (i, j) with nonzero similarity, there should be either (i, j, s<sub>ij</sub>) or (j, i, s<sub>ji</sub>) in the input. **Tuples with i = j are ignored, because we assume s<sub>ij</sub> = 0.0.**

Because this says tuples with i = j are assumed to have a similarity of 0.0, I reason that the smaller the value of s<sub>ij</sub> is, the more similar i and j are, to the point that a similarity of 0.0 means they are identical.

The [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/mllib-clustering.html#power-iteration-clustering-pic) for Power iteration clustering says the following in relation to missing pairs of i,j.

> If a pair is missing from input, their similarity is treated as zero.

I would reason from this that either zero equates to completely dissimilar, or the default treatment of missing pairs is to treat them as  equal.

I find it hard to believe that the missing pairs in a sparse affinity matrix would be treated as identical, which means these two documentation sources are in opposition. So which one is correct? Does a similarity of 0 mean a pair is identical, or as different as can be?

Comment: I believe that it's a documentation error. I'll open a JIRA issue when I'll connect on my PC.

Comment: I think you're probably correct, but which documentation is wrong?

Comment: I believe that when the similarity equals 1 i=j. But I have to check the paper again and the code. It's not very practical to read those two on a mobile phone

Comment: Did you ever get a chance to look at this? I've tried clustering the very small sample set given in the example doc and it seems pretty much randomly clustered.